# main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with.. main.jsbundle issue after upgrading to react-native 0.63

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.0",

Encountered the below main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with issue when trying to archive after upgrading to react-native 0.63. was wondering if anyone encounters the same issue

[image]

Comment: In my case this seems to be related to using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` for short absolute imports. Looking closer at the build logs, I can see that it fails to generate the jsbundle the first time it hits one of these imports. I haven't found a solution yet. I assume going back to relative imports would work...

Comment: @IsaacOveracker Same exact situation here. I wonder if it's this plugin in particular that's not working for some reason, or if other babel functionality isn't working too.

Comment: @EmpireJones I noticed that I had the default generated `.babelrc` file in addition to a `babel.config.js` where I had configured the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` settings. I removed `.babelrc` and got further in generating the jsbundle, but ran into a different error related to my monorepo nohoist rules missing a few libs. Why this only fails on 0.63.0 and not 0.62.2 is still eluding me. I've made it a bit further, but now I have errors similar to Sachanski's answer--relative imports.

Comment: @EmpireJones I found a solution. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887575/49941) below.

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me in a project involving `babel-plugin-module-resolver`:

1. Open your `ios/*.xcworkspace` in Xcode.
2. Click on the name of your project in the project navigator.
3. Click on the name of your target in the pane on the left.
4. Click on Build Phases.
5. Expand the *Bundle React Native code and images* phase.
6. On the first line of the script, add `cd $PROJECT_DIR/..` to go up a directory.

The whole script should look like this:

```
cd $PROJECT_DIR/..
export NODE_BINARY=node
./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

Note that this might break if the source of this is a bug in 0.63.0, so you may need to undo this on a future release.

Props to @typester for bringing this up on [facebook/react-native #29351](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29351#issuecomment-657906376).

Comment: i didn't want to believe it but this worked for me too.  thank you!

Comment: Thanks you! I'd be interested to know why this worked over the original, which just pointed to ../node_modules.

Comment: no luck for me :(

Comment: No luck for me . Any one has working solution ?

Answer (score 18):

Found a solution

1. In Xcode Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, add `main.jsbundle`

[image]

2. In `package.json`, add

```
"scripts": {
    "bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "postinstall": "yarn run bundle:ios"
    ...
  },
```

so the `main.jsbundle` will be generated

Comment: Do you know what prompted this changed in the first place? It seems quite logical of course, but why wasn't the `react-native bundle` invocation needed before?

Comment: It works but strangely, all assets are missing, None of the images are showing

Comment: For me this works as well, but also no assets included.

Comment: Thanks a lot, baby. it's working. I was stuck since 5 hours and try so many solution. only your one worked. god bless

Comment: @UmangLoriya how did you resolve that images are not showing issue ?

Comment: @AkilaDevinda I am not remembering right now how I fixed the issue but yes, that was fixed, All my projects are now running RN version 0.67 or above so don't remember the exact solution now.

Comment: @AkilaDevinda just add assets folder also in `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`

Answer (score 4):

if you use M1'series Mac, you can try below.

1. select Xcode Build Phases tab
2. expand the Bundle React Native code and images phase
3. change script like below

```sh
cd $PROJECT_DIR/..
export NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/bin/node
./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

[image: operation image]

Answer (score 3):

For me the error occurred because I had imports like this:

```
import Component from '..';
```

Replacing those with relative paths (`@components/path/to/component`) fixed the issue.

Not sure why resolving these paths is problematic now.

I dug into the `node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/bundle/buildBundle.js` and placed a catch block in the `buildBundle` function in order to see the component(s) with the problematic import.

I think @changey's solution also works, it only requires adding an additional build step in the CI.

Comment: For me it was the `||=` operator that caused the metro-transform-worker to error

Answer (score 2):

Change your babel.config.js to .babelrc.js and it will work

Comment: This didn't change anything for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me but I fat-fingered the down vote and stackoverflow wont let me change it!

Comment: omg, after banging against this all day, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above fixed it for me, but it works with this PR, it'll probably be released soon https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29477

Just in case somebody finds it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from 0.62.5 to 0.63 and encountered the same error.

In my case, I found out the `react-native-xcode.sh` script executed in the "Bundle React Native code and images" build phase passed the wrong entry file (`index.js`) to the build command when it should have used `index.ios.js`. Not sure exactly why this changed in 0.63.

A solution that worked for me was specifying the correct entry file when running the script:

1. In Xcode, go to Build Phases -> Bundle React Native code and images
2. Change this part of the script
   `../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` to `ENTRY_FILE=index.ios.js ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`

Comment: but l don't have index.ios.js, can l still use index.ios.js?

Comment: @leeCoder Whatever your iOS entry file is (maybe you have a single index.js), just make sure the same file is used by the react-native-xcode.sh script.

Comment: Changing the entry point is not an answer. index.ios.js and index.android.ios are a platform specific file, a feature of RN, and synonomous with index.js. https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code . If you used the automatic upgrade, chances are the hermes setup broke in the process, causing your entry point issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seen similar issue with RN v0.63. Looking at the error logs noticed that the was an issue with Node memory out of range (EG failed to build bundle). I fixed this by adding:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1024
```

to `Bundle React Native code and images phase` script

EG:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1024
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non-standard Node.js installation, select your project in Xcode, find  'Build Phases' - 'Bundle React Native code and images' and change NODE_BINARY to an absolute path to your node executable. You can find it by invoking 'which node' in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there are several ways this can happen. Here is one problem/solution.

Our project is on RN 0.70.1, node 16.16.0 and my Xcode version is 14.3. I've found that Xcode terminal was using the system's node version of 12 out of `/usr/local/bin/node`. I did this by adding a script in the build phases to `echo $PATH`, then printing the node version `/usr/local/bin/node -v`.

A possible solution here could be to rename or remove the node version from `/usr/local/bin/node`, and then, since I use nvm as a node version manager, create a symlink to the newer node version like this `$sudo ln -s /Users/<your workspace>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 0):

As I ran `yarn bundle-ios`, the following message showed up.

> Unable to resolve module `config/dimension` from `src/scenes/Home/index.js`: config/dimension could not be found within the project.

I've been using `react-native-module-resolver`。 I configed "@configs" for path alias。 As you can see above the **@** is missing。

Corrected it, main.jsbundle was created, finally。

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/83777cb4fb5dda89c430b7eff9cd1f28d2577831), and is fixed in 0.63.3 https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0633

Just update to ^0.63.3 and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js` files in the same project. So RN could not find certain imported libraries. So l modified my **`.babelrc`** this way:

```
 {
   "extends": "./babel.config.js", 
   "plugins": [ //bla bla 

   ],
 }
```

this was how the error stopped for me.

Answer (score 0):

*This error is specific to the architecture settings of the Xcode project itself. When the wrong arch is set, you'll receive this error because the bundle failed to build.*

Here is an updated answer for anyone receiving this error on Xcode 12.5+

**Remove Cache, Reinstall Libraries, and Update Pods**

Sometimes this error is purely due to cache referencing a different architecture. Use the [react-native-clean-project](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project) utility to reset all cache related to the project, reinstall packages, and updates pods. This usually clears up the majority of my missing bundle errors.

**Verify Xcode Build Settings (Xcode 12.5+ on x86_64)**

**For Production:** you only need to make sure the Architectures settings set to Standard Architectures (default `${ARCHS_STANDARD}`). Excluded Architectures should be empty, and if VALID_ARCHS exists, be sure to rename it, then click Archive.

**Simulator:** You still need to add the VALID_ARCHS variable for the simulator, but set it to the project's **workspace**, setting the value to **x86_64**. In order to keep it a single setting for the entire project, make sure VALID_ARCHS isn't already set in Pods project or the App project. If it is, remove the variable, and then set the value on the workspace. Click Run to start your simulation build.

Now when you need to build for production, simply rename VALID_ARCHS to SIM_VALID_ARCHS, and then Archive.

Answer (score 0):

For those using expo `eas build`, I was having this same error after upgrading `react-native` and expo SDK. I fix it using changey solution by adding following to a script called by the hook `eas-build-post-install`:

```
if [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "ios" ]]; then
  echo "Creating main.jsbundle required during build process"
  react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/YOURPROJECTNAME/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
fi
```