# How do I see the logs added to the Xcode Build Phase Scripts in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: react-native, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild

I have a react native app within an `nx` monorepo that runs, archives, and builds successfully on my local machine.

I am trying to accomplish the same with Azure DevOps pipeline with the following XCode build task.

---

The Azure DevOps Xcode build task looks like this...

```yaml
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.scheme’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.xcodeVersion’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode Build to Generate the signed IPA'
  inputs:
    actions: 'clean build -verbose'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'apps/my-app/ios/MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: '$(Parameters.scheme)'
    xcodeVersion: '$(Parameters.xcodeVersion)'
    packageApp: true
    exportOptions: specify
    exportMethod: 'ad-hoc'
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

In the pipeline logs, I observed that it runs a task close to this...

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -workspace ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp clean build -verbose
```

I modified the paths as above and ran the task on local terminal and it builds successfully. It prints the logs I set in `Xcode` > `Target` (MyApp) > BuildPhases > `Bundle React Native code and images` as shown below

```
echo "\n 0. ⚛️ DEBUG PIPELINE: Bundle React Native code and images \n"
echo "\n 1. ⚛️ cd \$PROJECT_DIR/.."
pwd
ls

cd $PROJECT_DIR/..
export NODE_BINARY=node
./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

echo "\n 0.  DEBUG PIPELINE: Bundle React Native code and images::SCRIPT COMPLETED \n"
```

None of these logs show up in the pipeline. Even when I enable system diagnostics before running the pipeline with...

☑️ `Enable system diagnostics`

---

I [have](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29351#issuecomment-657929014) [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584957/react-native-main-jsbundle-does-not-exist-this-must-be-a-bug-with-cannot-conv) [these](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/141) [related](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15432) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806319/main-jsbundle-does-not-exist-this-must-be-a-bug-with-main-jsbundle-issue-afte/62914788#62914788) and [answers](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29351#issuecomment-657929014) and my attempt is at troubleshooting to see the what gets run.

Question: Does the Azure DevOps Xcode build task above use the same phase script? Does it remove the logs? Does it use another build phase script? How can I see the logs added to BuildPhase scripts in the AzurePipe line logs?

Thank you.